Google Play InAppBilling Error: "This version of the application is not configured for billing through Google Play"
I'm working on a .NET MAUI application where users can purchase subscriptions through Google Play and the App Store. I'm using the InAppBilling plugin for handling in-app purchases. It works smoothly on most devices, but on some Android devices, I'm getting the following error when trying to initiate a purchase:
This version of the application is not configured for billing through Google Play. Check the help center for more information.


Any suggestions on why this error occurs on specific devices or advice for resolving it across all devices would be greatly appreciated.
